# javassist works on simple java app but does not work within web app(spring)

Tags: javassist

I have simple java app with part of scala code and there are java agent which catch all methods i need and inject my code into them.

Problem appear when i try do the same action within web app(spring), but my agent only catch methods and inject code and when that methods is called my injecded code not run.

What is may be wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Desicion is to fix bugs in javaagent code, he is not printing stacktraces